# angular 2 settimeout this is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, settimeout

I'm trying to set up a setTimeout, inside a switch, that's inside a foreach, that's inside a function...

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.Data')

I have tried

```
import { DataProvider } from '../xml-provider';
constructor(private Data: DataProvider) { }
items = this.Data.xmldata['step'];  //XML turned into array using 

initiateStepActions(){
    var actionsToTake = this.items[this.currentStep]['timed_actions'];
    if (actionsToTake){
        this.items[this.currentStep]['timed_actions'][0]['action'].forEach(function(foundAction){
          switch (type) {
            case 'customerchat':
              var MesgObject = {text : foundAction['_']};
              //setTimeout(() => {this.Data.broadcastCustomerChatMesg(MesgObject)}, Number(foundAction['$']['showAtSecond']));
              //setTimeout (() => this.Data.broadcastCustomerChatMesg(MesgObject), Number(foundAction['$']['showAtSecond']));
              //setTimeout ( (this.Data.broadcastCustomerChatMesg(MesgObject)).bind(this), Number(foundAction['$']['showAtSecond']));
              //setTimeout (this.Data.broadcastCustomerChatMesg(MesgObject), Number(foundAction['$']['showAtSecond']));
              setTimeout (function(this) { this.Data.broadcastCustomerChatMesg(MesgObject)}, Number(foundAction['$']['showAtSecond']));

              TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.Data.broadcastCustomerChatMesg')
              break;

            case 'supportchat':
              console.log('send a support chat message ');
              break;

            default:
              console.log('defaulted');
          } //end switch
    });// end foreach
  }
}
```

All of them get the undefined error.

Comment: Post more code so we have some idea of what the calling context is (or what you're expecting it to be).

Comment: Can you add the surrounding foreach please?

Comment: added code, hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write

```
.forEach(function(foundAction){
```

`this` no longer references your class but the anonymous function. You should use arrow function

```
.forEach(fundAction => {
```

And do the same in the `setTimeout` to avoid passing the reference of `this`.

Comment: it's working .forEach((foundAction) => {  and then setTimeout(() => { did the trick!